# How to change controller when pressing a button , iOS?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, navigation

I put on my .xib file a navigation bar and a Bar Button Item.

I created an action for my button , i connected it and the action looks like this :

```
- (IBAction)AddAlert:(id)sender {

    self.addReminderViewController =[[AddReminderViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddReminderViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:addReminderViewController animated:YES];
}
```

where `AddReminderViewController` is the controller i want to navigate to.

My ViewController.h looks like this :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class AddReminderViewController;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) AddReminderViewController *addReminderViewController;

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *listData;

- (IBAction)AddAlert:(id)sender;

@end
```

where i declare the `@class AddreminderViewController` so that i can navigate there , and i synthesize the property on the .m file.

However when i press the button nothing happens. It doesnt crash! It just doesnt navigate me anywhere. Shall i make any changes to the AppDelegate? What am i missing here?

Comment: Are you sure your IBAction is connected properly to the touch up inside event of the button?

Comment: Hmm its a Bar Button Item , where can i see the option you are saying? In the connections inspector it just shows me that is connected with the action.

Comment: yes in connection inspector you could see that, try changing the parameter type `id` to `UIBarButtonItem *` in your `AddAlert` action

Comment: For the Bar Button Item i am using i can only see its connected to the AddAlert Action nothing else.

Comment: Took a bar button item from the items placed it on the navigation bar. Is connected to the AddAlert action i am showing above. I think that i should add something on my delegate file , for this kind of navigation to work but i am not sure

Comment: If you are connecting UIBarButtonItem properly with the selctor then it should work properly. you could try to put break point or `NSLog` in your method to see if it is being called or not?

Comment: it is called. i just did. also even when i am trying with a normal rect button , i cant change the controller.

Comment: so how your AppDelegate code looks like? you are using NavigationController? adding it to Window?

Comment: Its called both times. I think that it might be the controller i am trying to navigate to. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I meant that the nslog works both times. But it doesnt navigate me anywhere. So is the view that has the problem

Comment: When you say in your question:  "I put on my .xib file a navigation bar and a Bar Button Item", do you mean you physically added a navigation bar to your VC or do you mean you embedded the VC in a Nav Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `self.addReminderViewController` for initializing the controller but later you are ading without using self, Using the `self` makes sure the object retain count is set correctly.

In your code

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:addReminderViewController animated:YES];
```

try changing the above line and add self with `addReminderViewController`, it might solve your issue

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.addReminderViewController animated:YES];
```